# CakePHP 3.6.11: create dropdown in ctp from another controller

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox, dropdown, cakephp-3.6

I have `customers`(id, name) and `services` (id, title, isSubscription), I want to add a dropdown list in the `add.ctp` of `Customers` which will contain all the `titles` of `Services` where `isSubscription` is `true`. How I can achieve that?

There is no relation between `Customers` and `Services`, it will just populate the `customerServices` (customerid, serviceid) table with `id` of the specific customer and the `id` of the selected service.

Here is what I have tried:

in `ServicesController.php` in `add function`:

```
$services = $this->Services->find('list'); //the error is here because there is no relationship between Customers and Services
$this->set(compact('services'));
```

in `add.ctp` in `Template/Customers` :

```
$this->Form->control('category',array('options' => $services));
```

But I get this :

> Call to a member function find() on boolean

Comment: Do the blog tutorial in the official documentation. You obviously have not read about the very most basic tasks like passing a variable to the view layer. Your approach by getting spoon-fed by other people is flawed, start structured learning by reading the documentation.

Comment: @burzum thank you for your recommendation but I still can't find in the tutorial how to pass a `Services` list from `CustomerController` to the View. I would be glad if you can provide an example

Comment: @burzum please check the updated post.

Comment: I think the larger problem here is that there is in fact a relationship between customers and services based on your post. A customer can have many services and a service can belong to many customers. You should refactor your Cake tables to reflect this relationship and access the required data accordingly.

Comment: @DerekFulginiti the fact is that I didn't want to make a direct relationship because a customer can be without any services and a service can be without any customer, thats why I am using the customerServices table... But ofcourse as a newbie I don't know if that is the best way

Comment: That's fine. You should still set up the many-many relationship between the two tables through your customerServices join table

Comment: @netdev https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html The page that explains MVC mentions the concept as well, the view chapter as well. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation includes a section entitled [Getting Instances of a Table Class](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class), which shows exactly what you need:

```
TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Services')->find(...)
```